# plotting categorical data with yes no

Tags: excel, plot

I am trying to plot two categories which have ans in yes and no. I am not able to do it in excel. Is there any better way of doing it?
 an example is shown below:

```
        response1       response 2

type 1      yes           yes

type 2      no           yes
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel needs numbers in order to plot a chart. It can't plot text. You will need to count the number of Yes or No responses per type. This can be done with formulas like Countif() or without formulas, using a pivot table. The resulting numbers can then be plotted.

[image]